# Creating List of Custom Object F#

Tags: ios, swift, list, xamarin, f#

I have a custom object declared as follows:

```
class Listing : NSObject {
var from : Date?
var to : Date?
var pricePerNight : Int?
....
}
```

I then create an empty list of these objects like this:

```
var myListings = [Listing]()
```

I am now trying to create the same functionality using `F#` . I have defined an interface as follows:

```
type Listing = 

abstract member fromDate : NSDate with get,set
abstract member toDate : NSDate with get,set
abstract member pricePerNight : int with get,set
...
```

And then I did this:

```
    let listings : List<Listing> = List.Empty
```

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Whether your understanding is "correct" or not depends on what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to basically recreate the Swift code in F#, so that it has the same exact functionalities (appending to the list, varying size etc)

Comment: Then you'd have to either describe what the Swift code does, or wait for a person who knows both Swift and F#. Adding a "swift" tag to the question might help.

Comment: If you know Java, it basically works like an `ArrayList` and has the exact same behaviour and properties.

Comment: Yes, I figured what the list does. I'm more interested int he record syntax. I'm not entirely sure you're translating it into F# correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# `list` (which is not the same as Swift/C# `List`) is an immutable, singly linked list. It is more idiomatic as a F# data structure, has better support in the language (pattern matching, etc.), and since it's immutable you can safely make it public or share it between different threads. However, it is slower than many other data structures.

The F# equivalent of a Swift/C# `List` (in fact, it's exactly the same as a C# `List`) is called `ResizeArray`, which is a mutable array of automatically variable size. If you need your collection to be mutable, it's probably the data structure you want.

Either can be the correct choice, depending on what you want to do.